SQLAlchemy One to Many Relationship with Relationship to get Latest Based on Timestamp?
I'm using Python3.11 + SQLAlchemy 2.0.23. I have two models Project and Document. Document has project_id on it and a Project can have multiple Documents.
The issue is that I frequently need to get the latest document based on created_at on Document. So the user may request 100 out of their 10,000 projects and I want to get those 100 projects joined with each projects respective latest document. Is there a good way to represent that on a SQLAlchemy model as a relationship so that I can join on LatestDocument on that query?
Things I've considered:

Using a subquery whenever I need to do that join.

It mainly just feels like there's probably a better way I don't know about?


Adding a latest_document_id to Project

I'm concerned that this could fall out of sync with the actual list of Documents




Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/RelationshipToLatest
